# why the error : "reference to fixes is ambiguous" is occurring in the code?

Tags: c++

Here in this code codeblock is showing an error: reference to fixed is ambiguous, in line 52.
How to deal with that?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class fixed
{
    int p;
    int y;
    float r;
    float ret;
    public:
    fixed(){}
    fixed(int pf,int yf,float rf=0.18);
    fixed(int pf,int yf,int rf);
    void display(void);
};
fixed::fixed(int pf,int yf,float rf)
{
    p=pf;
    y=yf;
    r=rf;
    ret=pf;
    for(int i=0;i<yf;y++)
    {
        ret=ret*(1.0+rf);
    }
}
fixed::fixed(int pf,int yf,int rf)
{
    p=pf;
    y=yf;
    r=rf;
    ret=pf;
    for(int i=0;i<yf;y++)
    {
        ret=ret*( 1.0 + float(rf)/100);
    }
}
void fixed::display(void)
{
    cout<<"Principal value : " <<p<<endl;
    cout<<"return value : " <<r<<endl;
}
int main()
{

    int pa;
    int ya;
    float ra;
    int R;
    cout<<"Enter principal , time(in years) , rate(in decimal)"<<endl;
    cin>>pa>>ya>>ra;
    fixed fd1(pa,ya,ra);//here in this line 52 error is shown

    cout<<"Enter principal , time(in years) , rate(in percent)"<<endl;
    cin>>pa>>ya>>R;
    fixed fd2(pa,ya,R);

    cout<<"Enter principal and time(in years)"<<endl;
    cin>>pa>>ya;
    fixed fd3(pa,ya);

    fd1.display();
    fd2.display();
    fd3.display();
}
```

Comment: Because you've done `using namespace std;` and polluted your global namespace.  Try using `::fixed` on line 52.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `using namespace std` and there is a `std::fixed` as well as your `::fixed` type, so it is ambiguous.  The best solution might be to avoid `using namespace std` and also to avoid using names which collide with namespace std, but you can fixed it most quickly by changing `fixed fd1(...)` to `::fixed fd1(...)`.  The `::` on the front explicitly specifies that `fixed` is not within a namespace.